# How are websites actually made?

Tags: javascript, webserver

Every where I look, I see that websites can be created in several different ways. Some sources say that you have to use HTML and add Javascript, but there are others ways I have seen, like using Node.js(how can this thing create servers?). Apparently there are a multitude of ways to make websites. How do these different methods(Node.js) create websites, and **what is different from just using HTML and adding scripts to it**? Additionally, how do these websites become available to the public after creation? I'm interested in what goes on to create web servers and get them public, not what to write to make it happen.

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Comment: This question is very broad. Try searching for the answer first on google and if you have a more specific question ask it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you see in your browser is written in HTML/CSS. Your browser can display dynamic features by running JavaScript, as you said.

How this HTML and CSS is generated is where the various methods come into play.

An accessible web server will respond to any received requests (the internet is just a huge network). The web server looks at what resource was requested and will respond appropriately. This might involve running a PHP script, hitting an entry point in a C# application, or triggering an event in a Node.js application to name a few actions.

These actions all have something in common: they will result in some plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript/data being handed back to the web server, which is then sent back in the response.

In some cases, the HTML/CSS might be so simple that you can hand-write it and that's all there is to your website. Lots of websites have been written this way. No scripts or application needed (i.e., no PHP, Python, Node, C# etc).

However, if you want your website to be dynamic (e.g., simply display the current date and time) or big or complex or data-dependent, you wouldn't want to hand-write it. In this case, you would write some application or script on the server to generate the necessary HTML/CSS for you.

Answer (score 0):

To make a website public, you can just rent a hosting service and a domain name at a provider - google for "web hosting providers". You will be able to upload your files using FTP protocol and manage your database (usually MySQL) over some tool (most used is PhpMyAdmin).

I'm going to simplify what happens in the background.

1. The server needs to be connected to internet 24/7 (since the content it's hosting is available only when the server is connected).
2. Optionally (but very recommended), domain records need to point to the server's IP address(es)... Let's say your server has an IP address 12.34.56.78 - when you rent a domain called "example.com", you need to set its DNS record to point to this IP address so anyone who types in "example.com" into their browser, will communicate with your server.
3. The server software will see that someone is trying to communicate with it, requesting "example.com" on port 80 (http) and it will return content that has set up to return for this kind of request.